# Convert list of list into single list

Tags: python, list

Currently I have a list of lists

`l=[['asd'],['fgd']].`

I want to turn it into a list

`goal_list=['asd','fgd']`

but I do not know how to turn a list into the value inside it - does anyone have an idea how to this efficiently?

Comment: Several ways are available, have you tried any?

Comment: Play around with list indexes and you will get it :)

Comment: I tried iterating over the list, but was wondering if there might be some built-in function to it more efficiently :D. Thanks guys!

Comment: Such action is called `list flattening`. It could be done in many ways - search for `python list flattening` and choose method that fit your needs best.

Answer (score 0):

This is a perfect use-case for [itertools.chain](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain), where we essentially `chain` all sublists together to flatten them!

```
from itertools import chain

def single_list(arr):
    return list(chain(*arr))

print(single_list([['asd'],['fgd']]))
print(single_list([['asd', 'abcd'],['fgd', 'def']]))
```

The output will be

```
['asd', 'fgd']
['asd', 'abcd', 'fgd', 'def']
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use a list comprehension with two loops:

```
goal_list = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
```